# How to img src with javascript in a Ajax Weather

Tags: javascript

I'm a new web student and i'm writing some free Apis project.
I don't know how can i insert an icon movie(.svg) if some of the datas are largest or smallest from a number.
Can help me anyone?

```js
let info = document.querySelector('#weather-info'); 
document.querySelector('#city').addEventListener('change', function () {
    fetch(https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.value}&appid=2d89e68411ec3ef60dfdae66530bb266&lang=el&units=metric)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => info.innerHTML = ${data.weather[0].description},<br><strong>${data.main.temp}C<sup>o</sup></strong>,<br><br><span>Ταχύτητα Ανέμου</span> ${data.wind.speed} <span>Km/h</span>,)
})
```

Comment: if data.wind.speed is smallest of 3Km/h img src ="" and same think if is largest of 3.1 Km/h

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to insert an icon when the wind speed is less then 3km and a different icon if the wind speed is more then 3km.
I was clear now???

Comment: i make it...

$('.windmill').prop('src', (parseFloat(data.wind.speed) <= 3) ? 'images/ws1.svg' : 'images/ws2.svg')
                .removeClass('d-none');